# css calc(100%/5) with margins between calculated in

Tags: css, html

Can you use the css calc to make 5, 20% width divs floated in a row to equal 100%. My goal is to have 5 divs floating left, with a 1% margin between each of them. Currently I have to use first-of-type to remove the margin from the first div to try and align it perfectly with the left of the container. Any better solutions to this problem using the calc method?  I guess my issue is i dont know where to include the margins into the cacl.

```css
ul {
    width:500px;
}
li {
    width:calc(100%/5);
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:1%;
}
li:first-of-type{
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/1/
I can never get the fiddle linked right my bad

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `calc`? `100% / 5` will just result in 20%, so why not use 20% in the first place? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If I do that I think that all 5 divs will be adjacent with no margin between. I was wondering if the calc method could dived 100% by 5, then also include the margin between them, but not on the first or last divs sides touching the edge. Another soulution I was thinking about is to add box-sizing:padding-box to the divs and givving them all padding to make it apear as if they have space between each div. but then again, the first and last div wont be touching the sides of the container, there will be a little gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a neath trick to achieve this (it is what the Bootstrap 3 grid system is based on). You should add a **negative margin left and right** to your wrapper that equals the spacing between your blocks. This way you do not have to remove the left margin on your first block and the right margin on the last block. They will in fact be alligned perfectly with the edge, as the margin just overflows the wrapper. It is a bit hard to put into words in my not so fluent english, so have a look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/3/

```
ul {
    width:500px;
    margin: 0 -1%; /* this is the magic! */

}
li {
    width:19%;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:1%;
}
```

**edit:**

the right way to use trhis technique would in fact be like this:

```
 ul {
        margin: 0 -.5%; /* this is the magic! */
    }
    li {
        width:19%;
        background:blue;
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        margin-left:.5%;
        margin-right:.5%;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/7/

This way you spread the margin over the left and the right side. You'll have to set you're width on some wrapper element though, as I demonstrated in the fiddle

Comment: haha magic yes! I do feel a little dirty with this trick thou, but even when I change the ul to 100% it still is consistent. https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/6/

Comment: Please note that this doesn't utilize the maximum width available for the `li`s and the `li`s are narrower than what they can be.

Comment: It is actually perfectly okay to use negative margins, and well supported in all browsers http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/ I admit it feels a bit unnatural, but it really isn't, there is a reason why TB3 uses it.

Comment: @arbel you are absolutely right. My update should be correct though.

Comment: very interesting technique, but It seems missing 1px on the far right - https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/8/

Comment: @sdcr That is a rounding issue, since we are working with percentages for margins, and there is no such thing as halve a pixel. Change the width to 501px and you'll see it is solved. Personally I would work with hard pixel values for the margins though, this way you'll never see the issue, no matter the width (one block will be a pixel less wide probably, but you won't notice)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `1%` margin in your width calculation. Something like:

```
width: calc((-1 * 1%) + (100% / 5));
```

See here:

```css
ul {
    width:500px;
}
li {
    width: calc((-1 * 1%) + (100% / 5));
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:1%;
}
li:first-of-type{
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use calc at all here, since your div's width will always be 20% (width a 1% margin making it 19% width to fit in a single line).

Demo:

```css
ul {
    width:500px;
}
li {
    width:19.2%;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:1%;
}
li:first-of-type{
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I do that then I will have 4 gabs between the 5 divs, 19% x 5 = 95% that means each margin needs to be 1.25% ? im just wondering if there is a way for the calc method to do this math for me?

Comment: this isn't really what the calc function is used for. It is used when you have two different units, and are doing a 'calculated 'conversion between the two units.

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this, it seems a bit pointless. Here's your fiddle corrected:

https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/2/

The problem was adding margin to the li's:

```
li {
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

Just like a grid, margin adds to the outside of widths, meaning you really had 105% width instead of 100%. Make sure to use padding instead and nest a div inside with the content you want:

```
li {
    background:blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
li div {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `calc` function for this. You can just do the calculations manually:

(100% - 4% margins) / 5 elements = 19.2% width (not 19%).

You will, however, need to either only apply the left margin to the last four list items (`li:not(:first-of-type) { margin-left: 1%; }`) or remove it from the first one (like you already do).

```css
ul {
  width: 500px;
}
li {
  width: 19.2%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 `li`s with 4 of them with a `1%` margin on the left.

So you should do `calc(96% / 5)` instead of `calc(100% / 5)`

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/qrd702dj/5/